# I can not call a method with varargs from JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, variadic-functions

I have class `DBBase` defined as follow in my application:

```
public class DBBase {
    public static void close(Statement stmt) {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception:(", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet resultSet) {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception:(", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection con) {
        try {
            if (con != null) con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception:(", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Object... closeable) {
        for (Object obj : closeable) {
            if (obj != null) {
                if (obj instanceof Connection) close((Connection) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof ResultSet) close((ResultSet) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Statement) close((Statement) obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the close method `DBBase.close(con, stmt, resSet)` from another class, everything works fine but when I call this method from a `JSP` page I got the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file: /admin/test.jsp
Generated servlet error:
The method close(Statement) in the type DBBase is not applicable for the arguments (Connection, Statement, ResultSet)
```

And this is my JSP page:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="db.DBBase" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet resSet = null;

    try {
        // Some code here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DBBase.close(con, stmt, resSet);
    }
%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test JSP File</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

My JDK version is 1.7.0._51 with language level 7

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

This is my server and jsp configs:

```
Server Version: Apache Tomcat/5.5.17
Servlet Version: 2.4
JSP Version: 2.0
```

Actually I have JBoss 4.0.4 GA

**UPDATE**

Regarding to @AlexC's comments I have to change my JBoss version to use varargs.

Comment: Try to post your jsp page?

Comment: Does it work if you make the first 3 methods private?

Comment: Post which app server and servlet and jsp level you are using.  So JSR-245 for JSP 2.1 defined usage of varargs in JSP and in Tomcat this was done during 7.x release cycle.  (See  http://alex-perevalov.livejournal.com/30156.html and  https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications ).

Comment: @AlexC how can I change my jsp version?

Comment: @whistling_marmot no the problem exists

Comment: the workaround for you would be to pass a collection to the method..

Comment: Usually in web.xml (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)

Comment: @AlexC I think I have to change my JBoss version

Comment: Yes, your version does not support JSP 2.1 required for vararg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSR-245 for JSP 2.1 defined usage of varargs in JSP and in Tomcat this was done during 7.x release cycle. (See http://alex-perevalov.livejournal.com/30156.html and https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications )

In in web.xml (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html ) you can specify the JSP version to support if you need to limit it.

Upgrading your app server to JSP 2.1 compatible one should allow varargs.